# Cordova iOS Ajax returns 404 after switching from WiFi to cellular connection

Tags: ios, ajax, cordova, phonegap-plugins

Here is the problem:
When doing ajax call on wifi connection, POST call works as expected. Then I'm switching to cellular (4g, same app instance) and I'm doing same POST request - now I'm getting 404 error. After about 1-2 minutes, cellular starts to work.

Doing first request on 4g then on wifi seems to work fine.

I have whitelist plugin installed, version 1.2.1. iOS v9.2

Comment: It turns out that it also results in "Internet connection was lost" sometimes.

Comment: When you switch from wifi to cellular it takes a while until the connection starts working, but 1-2 minutes seems a lot to me. Anyway, this isn't a cordova or a programming issue.